# Reaction of copper oxide with acid

Tags: acid-base, ionic-compounds, electronegativity

Copper metal is less electropositive than hydrogen and thus less reactive. It is unable to displace hydrogen ions from a solution of sulfuric(IV) acid.

Why then would copper oxide or copper carbonate react with sulfuric acid?

$$CuO(s)+H_2SO_4(aq)\longrightarrow CuSO_4 (aq)+ H_2O(l)$$
$$CuCO_3(s)+H_2SO_4(aq)\longrightarrow CuSO_4(aq) + H_2O(l)+CO_2(g)$$

Is it because copper ions are just spectator ions, where the real reaction happens between hydrogen ions and oxygen ions?

$$Cu^\mathrm{2+} O^\mathrm{2-} + 2H^+ +SO_4^\mathrm{2-}(aq)\longrightarrow Cu^\mathrm{2+} + SO_4^\mathrm{2-} + H_2O$$

Therefore the ionic equation is only:

$$2H^+ + O^\mathrm{2-} \longrightarrow H_2O$$

Therefore it does not matter whether copper is less electropositive than hydrogen, since the only reaction that happens is between hydrogen and oxygen?

Comment: This analysis seems vague to me there are many considerations such as lattice energy, hydration energy we cannot simply write the compound as it has split into ions

Comment: If it was true all oxides would be solube in water and there would be no classification of an oxide such as acidic or basic

Comment: In any case, regardless of quantification of CuO solubility in water or acides, it is not a redox reaction, but acido-basic reaction. In final state, $\ce{Cu^2+}$ goes to solution, and $\ce{O^2-}$  as a very strong base reacts with $\ce{H+}$.

Comment: I don't understand quite the premise of your question. The net reaction says that there is no redox couple involving copper, which is what you expected. The reactions that you've written down are all consistent with that observation. What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it because copper ions are just spectator ions, where the real reaction happens between hydrogen ions and oxygen ions?
>
> ...
>
> Therefore it does not matter whether copper is less electropositive than hydrogen, since the only reaction that happens is between hydrogen and oxygen?

Absolutely. Copper does not change its oxidation state.

Edit: To ???, please justify your downvotes. The question is about reactivity which may happen at solid-liquid-interfaces, too, not about solubility.